# Pandas - styling with multi-index (from pivot)

Tags: pandas, styles, multi-index

As a result of pivot table I get the following table.

[Entry table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhKP4.png)

I would like to apply a style with a criteria depending on the product =

- when eggs are sold I would like to have a red background when sales is lower than 15
- when chicken is sold I would like to have a red background when sales is lower than 18

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kruJQ.png)

I am able to do it converting to records (pd.to_record) creating a single index but I am loosing the nice layout allowing to compare evolution between months. Note the number of month is variable (can be 2 in example but more).

Entry file is read from Excell=

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('xxx.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet')
```

```
result =
   product      Month  sales  revenue
0     eggs 2021-05-01     10      8.0
1  chicken 2021-05-01     15     12.0
2  chicken 2021-05-01     17     15.0
3     eggs 2021-05-01     20     15.0
4     eggs 2021-06-01     11      8.5
5  chicken 2021-06-01     14     12.0
6  chicken 2021-06-01     18     15.0
7     eggs 2021-06-01     22     17.0
```

Pivoting it and then swaping it =

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, columns = ['Month'], index = ['product'], values = ['sales','product'],aggfunc=sum)
df3 = df2.swaplevel(0,1,1).sort_values(by='Month',ascending=True, axis=1)
```

```
Month   2021-05-01       2021-06-01
           revenue sales    revenue sales
product
chicken       27.0    32       27.0    32
eggs          23.0    30       25.5    33
```

The df-to-dict() =

```
{(Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 'revenue'): {'chicken': 27.0, 'eggs': 23.0}, (Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {'chicken': 32, 'eggs': 30}, (Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 'revenue'): {'chicken': 27.0, 'eggs': 25.5}, (Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {'chicken': 32, 'eggs': 33}}
```

Thanks in advance for help you can provide.

Comment: The styler won't work with a non-unique index like that. Do you actually have an index with multiple occurrences of `egg` and `chicken` in the index?

Comment: Perhaps if you could include code to build the dataframe it would be easier to see what the underlying structure is. Something like the output from `df.to_dict()` or `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: My df is built by reading several excell documents from a database (one per month) appending them, creating the Month information, and then PIVOTING it. Then I try to highlight informations based on a multicriteria...

Comment: @Henry = I just added equivalent (a bit simplified ;-)) of my code so you understand the structure.